# How to move EF migration and update database in Azure SQL DB

Tags: sql, azure, entity-framework, migration, visual-studio-2019

I have an Entity framework project created in Visual Studio 2019.
I have created a migration using Add-migration, and have updated the local SQL DB using Update-database. The changes in migration are reflected in (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB. Everything is working as it should.

Now I want to publish my application from VS, and want the changes in my migration and local DB to move/migrate to the Azure SQL DB for use by masses.

How do I make sure after publishing, the changes have migrated to the Azure SQL DB?
Thanks,
KB

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to azure database from your local just do `Update-Database` with azure database connection string. otherwise, you should do this somewhere in your application:

```
yourDbContext.Database.Migrate();
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your answer. So, I can access the Azure DB from my management Studio. Are you saying I should do a migration and update-database using the the syntax you have specified? Can you elaborate on your solution, and outline the commands I need to use please? Is that prior to publishing, or before? Thanks.

Comment: In my opinion it's better to deploy first and if was successful then do the migration, so it should after publish on server. After deploy application just run database update with azure connection string and maybe you dont need the use ``Migrate`` function